# Sql return last order details for each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Using SQL Server 2012.

I have a table `T_Orders` with few columns with the order details. In the table there are also columns `ClientID -int`, `OrderDateTime - smalldatetime`.

How can I return the last order for each client?

The problem is that if I do something like this :

```
select max(OrderDateTime), ClientID 
from t_Orders 
group by ClientID
```

I will not get the rest of the information about the order because I didn't select all the columns. If I select all the columns, I will have to group by all of them and the result will not be the last order for this client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually solved using window functions:

```
select *
from (
  select o.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by o.ClientID order by o.OrderDateTime desc) as rn
  from t_orders o
) t
where rn = 1
order by ClientId;
```